# Menu item in html site not working

Tags: javascript, html

I want dropdown menu also to be able to click the item. Example:

Menu item: Services

```
Sub items:    - branding  } These already have working links  
              - marketing }
```

But when I replace # with a link for Services, it does not work. when i click it nothing happens although if I right click and open in new tab it opens the URL.

I think it's related to the Javascript.

HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle js-activated">Services</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="index.html">YouTube</a></li>
      <li><a href="index2.html">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio-post.html">Instagram</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio-post2.html">Facebook</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.js-activated').dropdownHover({
      instantlyCloseOthers: false,
      delay: 0
  }).dropdown();

  $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
   });

});
```

Comment: This is bootstrap? Try `<a href"/link/to/services.html" data-target="#" .....`

Answer (score 0):

this code:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

disables the default action (redirecting) on a click on 'a' element within the menu.

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Solved by deleting that code and also

    .dropdown()
therefore the code is:

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.js-activated').dropdownHover({
       instantlyCloseOthers: false,
       delay: 0
      });
    });